# Current Account deficit but FX appreciating?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, foreign-exchange

When the Current Account (CA) is in deficit it means there is less demand for a currency than supply so it should theoretically depreciate but sometimes this does not hold. When a country with CA deficit sees its currency appreciating what could the be the driver, assuming the central bank does not intervene? An example could be the USD appreciating in 2022-2023 despite CA deficit and obviously the Fed not intervening.

Comment: The current account has very little to do with FX rates. In fact most theories don't even look at the current account at all. See [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/67940/54838) for a decent summary of FX rate determination theories.